# Calling setTimeout() for all members in object - Never called for 1st member, and called for 2nd member. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, closures, settimeout

I have a 3D array (rather JS object), called `outerArray` in the SSCCE I am posting here in this question, and it contains inner arrays (rather objects), each of which contains several *url* objects, each of which contains a `url` field and an `interval` field.

For a given inner array (rather object), the value of `interval` field for each `url` will be the same. That is how they have been grouped.

My purpose is that , for each inner array, I send an AJAX request periodically at regular intervals, and the value of this interval is determined by the `interval` field in individual urls.  Then on the basis of output of the AJAX request, I make some changes in the DOM.

I expected that from the code given below, but the problem is that it does enter the `next()` function **for the first inner array (i.e. the urls with interval 7), but then never calls the `setTimeout()` function**, and goes on to call the `next()` function for the next inner array (i.e. the urls with interval 10) for which it then does call the `setTimeout()` inside which it calls the `next()` function again, and the process goes on...

**My question is that why does the control never enter `setTimeout()` for the first inner array (urls with interval 7)? Why am I getting this unexpected behavior?**

***CONSOLE OUTPUT:***

```
Function loop iteration 0 for urls with interval 7

Function loop iteration 0 for urls with interval 10

setTimeout() called for urls with interval 10
Success for AJAX request for urls with interval 10

Function loop iteration 1 for urls with interval 10

setTimeout() called for urls with interval 10
Success for AJAX request for urls with interval 10

Function loop iteration 1 for urls with interval 10

setTimeout() called for urls with interval 10
Success for AJAX request for urls with interval 10

Function loop iteration 2 for urls with interval 10

setTimeout() called for urls with interval 10
Success for AJAX request for urls with interval 10

Function loop iteration 2 for urls with interval 10
...
```

***scripts.js:***

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var outerArray = {
        0 : {
            0 : {
                url: "abc.example.com",
                interval: 7
            },
            1 : {
                url: "def.example.com",
                interval: 7
            }
        },

        1 : {
            0 : {
                url: "ghi.example.com",
                interval: 10
            }
        }
    };




    for (var innerArrayKey in outerArray) {
        var innerArray = outerArray[innerArrayKey];

        (function next(index) {
                console.log("Function loop iteration " + index + "for urls with interval " + innerArray[0]["interval"]);//check
                setTimeout(function() {
                    console.log("setTimeout() called for urls with interval " + innerArray[0]["interval"]);//check
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://xxx.yyy.xx.yy/testAsynchronousJSRequests/ajax.php",
                        method: "post",
                        data: { innerArray : innerArray },
                        success: function(dataReturned, stringStatus, jqXHR) {
                            console.log("Success for AJAX request for urls with interval " + innerArray[0]["interval"]);//check
                            next(index+1);
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, stringStatus, stringExceptionThrown) {
                            console.log("Error in AJAX request " + innerArray[0]["interval"]);//check
                        }
                    });
                }, (innerArray[0]["interval"]*1000) );

        })(0);
    }

});
```

***ajax.php:***

```
<?php 

print_r($_POST["innerArray"]);

?>
```

***index.php:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to the scope of setTimeout, with your current code what happens is that when setTimeout gets executed it reads the last value for innerArray which points to the array of interval 10. There are 2 ways (at least) to solve this:

1) Using immediately invoked function wrapper to create a separate scope for each setTimeout with proper reference to the  **innerArray** variable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var outerArray = {
        0: {
            0: {
                url: "abc.example.com",
                interval: 7
            },
            1: {
                url: "def.example.com",
                interval: 7
            }
        },

        1: {
            0: {
                url: "ghi.example.com",
                interval: 10
            }
        }
    };




    for (var innerArrayKey in outerArray) {
        var innerArray = outerArray[innerArrayKey];

        (function next(index) {
            console.log("Function loop iteration " + index + " for urls with interval " + innerArray[0]["interval"]); //check
            setTimeout(function(innerArray) {
                return function() {
                    console.log("setTimeout() called for urls with interval " + innerArray[0]["interval"]); //check
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://xxx.yyy.xx.yy/testAsynchronousJSRequests/ajax.php",
                        method: "post",
                        data: {
                            innerArray: innerArray
                        },
                        success: function(dataReturned, stringStatus, jqXHR) {
                            console.log("Success for AJAX request for urls with interval " + innerArray[0]["interval"]); //check
                            next(index + 1);
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, stringStatus, stringExceptionThrown) {
                            console.log("Error in AJAX request " + innerArray[0]["interval"]); //check
                        }
                    });
                }
            } (innerArray), (innerArray[0]["interval"] * 1000));

        })(0);
    }

});
```

2) Using ES6 **let** keyword which creates a separate scope for each iteraion:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var outerArray = {
        0: {
            0: {
                url: "abc.example.com",
                interval: 7
            },
            1: {
                url: "def.example.com",
                interval: 7
            }
        },

        1: {
            0: {
                url: "ghi.example.com",
                interval: 10
            }
        }
    };




    for (var innerArrayKey in outerArray) {
        let innerArray = outerArray[innerArrayKey];

        (function next(index) {
            console.log("Function loop iteration " + index + " for urls with interval " + innerArray[0]["interval"]); //check
            setTimeout(function() {
                console.log("setTimeout() called for urls with interval " + innerArray[0]["interval"]); //check
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://xxx.yyy.xx.yy/testAsynchronousJSRequests/ajax.php",
                    method: "post",
                    data: {
                        innerArray: innerArray
                    },
                    success: function(dataReturned, stringStatus, jqXHR) {
                        console.log("Success for AJAX request for urls with interval " + innerArray[0]["interval"]); //check
                        next(index + 1);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, stringStatus, stringExceptionThrown) {
                        console.log("Error in AJAX request " + innerArray[0]["interval"]); //check
                    }
                });
            }, (innerArray[0]["interval"] * 1000));

        })(0);
    }

});
```

You may check this to understand more:
[JavaScript Closures: setTimeout Inside a For Loop](https://wsvincent.com/javascript-closure-settimeout-for-loop/)